# Add offset to UITableViewCell at time of creation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout

I'm struggling to load a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in such way so that I can give a custom offset to one cell only - in my case only to Cell 1, Section 1. I'd like to give a custom offset to the cell, as the same cell (xib) is used in other parts of the project where it extends to the edges of the table without any offset. All my cells are designed as *.xib files. I'm willing to set something in `awakeFromNib()` or other methods, if there's the need for that.

[image]

Is there any way to set the cell offset, inset, margins, padding (not sure about the correct wording) at time of the creation or at time of loading of the cell?

I've tried to set margins in this way, but it doesn't work:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row) == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
        return cell
    }
} else {
    // Load other cells
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to use a section header.

Comment: @shallowThought Interesting idea. Can you expand a little bit? I've implemented the `viewForHeaderInSection` where I'm returning `MyCell()` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and it doesn't work. I'm getting just an empty header. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Your header needs to be a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation. Try applying the margins to the cell's contentView (the superview for your cell's content, and a subview of the cell). You may also have to set the cell's background colour to clear (the contentView will still be white).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row) == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
        return cell
    }
} else {
    // Load other cells
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark I've implemented all combinations of `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)`, `cell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)` and also `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`, but the cell still expands to the edges. Any ideas?

Comment: The table view may be overriding your `layoutMargins`. Setting the `layoutMargins` on the `contentView` would inset your content (if you anchored it to the margins), but your `contentView` itself won't change. You could add a subView to your `contentView` (to contain all your labels etc), anchor that to the margins of `contentView`, and set the `contentView`'s background colour to clear. You would then be able to set the `contentView`'s layoutMargins.